# DeleteDuplicate of list within list using a criterion

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following list of points (x,y):

```
list = {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {2.1,2}, {2.001,2}, {1.001,1.001}, {1.1,1.001} };
```

How can it be efficiently reduced to:

```
newList = {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {2.1,2}, {1.1,1.001}};
```

i.e, given a criterion (that can be either the metric distance or rounded number), how can I remove elements from the above list?

Comment: Have you seen `DeleteDuplicatesBy`?

Comment: `Union[list, SameTest -> (Norm@#1 - Norm@#2 < 10^-2 &)]`

Comment: This answer is wrong, it removes all duplicates but does not reduce it to 1. If u consider my example u get: newList = {{3,3},{2.1,2}};